# Magento2 call to specific function in controller

Tags: magento2, ajax

I have a controller class called Index that is called in a javascript AJAX request, but rather than have the code in the constructor i would like to call specific functions in the Index.php, so i dont have to create a seperate class for every required function. Is it possible to call SavePricingChanges function from javascript?

> Vendor/Pricing/Controller/Adminhtml/Ajaxcontroller/Index.php

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Pricing\Controller\Adminhtml\Ajaxcontroller;

use Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\JsonFactory;
use Magento\Customer\Model\Session;

class Index extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{
    /**
     * @var JsonFactory
     */
    private $resultJsonFactory;
        /**
     * @var Session
     */
    private $customerSession;
   
    /**
     * @param JsonFactory $resultJsonFactory
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
        JsonFactory $resultJsonFactory,
        Session $customerSession
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context);
        $this->resultJsonFactory = $resultJsonFactory;
        $this->customerSession = $customerSession;
    }

    /**
     * @return \Magento\Framework\App\ResponseInterface|\Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\Json|\Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultInterface
     */
    public function execute()
    {
        
    }

    public function SavePricingChanges(){
        $response = $this->resultFactory
             ->create(\Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultFactory::TYPE_JSON)
             ->setData([
                 'status'  => "success",
                 'message' => "form submitted correctly"
             ]);

        return $response;  
    }
}
```

> etc/adminhtml/routes.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:App/etc/routes.xsd">
        <router id="admin">
            <route id="adminpath" frontName="adminpath">
                <module name="Vendor_Pricing" />
            </route>
        </router>
    </config>
```

> my javascript in the phtml file

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    require(["jquery"],function($) {
        $('#savePricing').click(function() {
            var customurl = "<?php echo $block->getUrl('adminpath/ajaxcontroller'); ?>";
            $.ajax({
                url: customurl,
                type: 'POST',
                dataType: 'json',
                data: {form_key: window.FORM_KEY},
                showLoader: true,
            complete: function(response) {             
                var status = response.responseJSON.status;       
                   if(status == "success"){
                        //there is a response from index.php
                   }   
                },
                error: function (xhr, status, errorThrown) {
                    console.log('Error happens. Try again. error : ' + errorThrown);
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

I can get a response if i put the code from Index.php in the constructor but i need to call specific functions

Answer (score 0):

Magento 2 controller has execute method which only gets called.

For your application you can create a separate class **(a block or helper)** that handles the logic you want
In the existing controller, you can inject that class & call its methods.

Below is the example :-

```
class Index extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{
     protected $helperData;

     public function __construct(
          \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
          \{Vendor}\{Module}\Helper\Data $helperData
     ){
           $this->helperData = $helperData;
           parent::__construct($context, $helperData);
     }

     public function execute()
     {
           $this->helperData-><functionName>();
           return;     
     }
}
```